# Google Apps Script (GAS) & Google Sheets: how to get spreadsheetId?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm noob in Google Apps Script (GAS) & intensively reading & trying out appropriate docs.
I'm writing here in hope that someone already knows the answers to my question.
Below GAS returns error on "ReferenceError: spreadsheetId is not defined".

Question: anyone knows how to get spreadsheetId in the GAS?

```
function myFunction() {

  var sheet = Sheets.newSpreadsheet();
  var title = 'title';
  sheet.properties = Sheets.newSpreadsheetProperties();
  sheet.properties.title = title;
  var spreadsheet = Sheets.Spreadsheets.create(sheet);
}



function writeToSheet() {

var values = [
  [
    // Cell values ...
  ]
  // Additional rows ...
];
var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
valueRange.values = values;
var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, {
  valueInputOption: valueInputOption
});


}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your script, when you want to put the values with `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update`, after the new Google Spreadsheet was created with `Sheets.Spreadsheets.create`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // This is your script of "myFunction".
  var sheet = Sheets.newSpreadsheet();
  var title = 'title';
  sheet.properties = Sheets.newSpreadsheetProperties();
  sheet.properties.title = title;
  var spreadsheet = Sheets.Spreadsheets.create(sheet);

  // --- I added the following script.
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.spreadsheetId;
  var valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
  var range = "A1";
  var values = [["a1", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"]];
  // ---

  // This is your script of "writeToSheet".
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, {
    valueInputOption: valueInputOption
  });
}
```

- When above script is run, a new Spreadsheet created and the values of `[["a1", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"]]` are put to the 1st tab.
- `spreadsheetId` can be retrieved from `var spreadsheet = Sheets.Spreadsheets.create(sheet)` like `spreadsheet.spreadsheetId`.
- In this case, `valueInputOption` and `range` are required to be set. In this modification, as the sample values, `USER_ENTERED` and `A1` are used, respectively.

  - For `range`, when the sheet name is not used, the value is put to the 1st tab. In your case, the created new Spreadsheet has only one tab. So I thought that this might be suitable.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that Sheets API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)