# How to run a basic spreadsheet app with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

How would I run the below function:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpjBD.png)

The "run" button is greyed out.  Looking to keep the app independent of the spreadsheet itself.

see also:

[Google Apps Script (GAS) & Google Sheets: how to get spreadsheetId?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66154159/22063140)

Comment: Please post code as text [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Don't  use indefinite ranges with Google Apps Script

Answer (score 0):

working code:

```
function myFunction() {
  //Browser.msgBox("Hello World!");
  Logger.log("foobar"); 
}
```

I think that I just needed to click the "save project" button, but will confirm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).